# Get Page <title> with PHP That Has Value Echoed by PHP

Tags: php, html

I have pages that the page title is generated by PHP code. The reason for that is for easier management of the title. So it looks like below

```
<title><?php echo $var['WIN_TITLE_HOME'] ?></title>
```

I have search functionality being developed in another page that will display the value of `<title>` if the search string is found on the particular page. My code to find the title is

```
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/", $contents, $page_title);
```

However as what I can see, if the search result exists, the page `title` is missing. I believe it is because I am getting the content of the file, and the title needs PHP to process it. Those codes work fine if the `title` is written like `<title>Some Title Here</title>`. Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do file_get_contents against a rendered PHP page.  This would pull the PHP rendered page into the variable, title and all.  Though you will run into issues if you have user session management(the web server would not be logged in with an active session).

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://path.to/page.php");
```

Comment: thank you, the above solution worked perfectly. but I am wondering if there will be any performance issue if I have tons of pages to be rendered?

Comment: It could, yes.  Another option would be to create an index DB of pages/titles, then reference that for your search.

Comment: Creating the pages/files list to be searched in is the really nice idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your assumption that it is getting the code but not processing it to get the dynamic title. Without knowing more about the code, my solution would be to rewrite the code your using to get the title in the other page into the one where you are attempting to retrieve the title.

Comment: rewrite? for example?

Comment: You have existing code in the  php file <?php echo $var['WIN_TITLE_HOME'] ?> and the code that is getting the title variable. I would copy it form there and then put it into the page you are trying to pull it into. That may not be possible depending on if it is using a post or get.

Comment: if I rewrite that in my search page, I will need to put lots of `if else` (maybe). I like to automatically take the `title` from the page, that is preferred.

Comment: ok, how about this, use AJAX to do a XHTTP and then return the title on the on load event.

Comment: I think that is more processes involved if I do that. At the moment, I use `stream_context_create` and set the small value of timeout for my `file_get_contents()` because `title` won't take much time to be rendered. I think.

Comment: You are right, it will be more processes involved and be more consuming of resources. The way you are doing it should be ok. If you do ever want to try writing the code in the other you could try using `include` which includes another file and if it included file has php will render it to the page it is being included on.

Comment: OK thanks for your opinion & thoughts. I really appreciate it. Cheers.